# Attaching punch bag bracket to pebble dash exterior wall

Tags: exterior, render

the outside of my house is pebble dashed like the image below

[image: pebble dash exterior]

I want to attach a punch bag bracket to the wall, like the image below

[image]

Mt main concerns are cracking

- Cracking the pebble dash render - when drilling for the bracket
- Letting water get in behind the render once its drilled, thus damaging it
- The force of hitting the punch bag may crack the render

Any ideas on how i could get around these issues ?

Comment: why not get a free standing unit?

Comment: Did you just get a paint/stucco job done?

Comment: No the stucco is about old 30 yrs +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it!

Former boxer here.  I put up a mounting kit in my joists in an apartment I had in college...  I split both joists it was mounted too.  I was using a 100lb water bag and weight makes a huge difference.  But I don't care if it is 25lb.  Don't do it.

Buy a pole and mount it to that and they sell [punching bag stands](http://www.walmart.com/ip/15063341?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227000000000&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=21486607510&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=19880599990&veh=sem).  The link isn't an endorsement, just an example.  Also if you mount it to your house you will have probably only 60 degrees of hitting - 30 on each side given you don't want to pop the bag directly into your house each time.

Note that you are probably attaching this to wood.  Assemblies like this are not supposed to go into wood - needs metal.  You screw this into wood and the constant reverberation, up/down/side forces will slowly make the screw hole bigger and they will eventually wiggle out over time - for sure.